# A game like Doodle Jump. I fly through the collider platforms instead of jumping on them. Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The platforms have Edge Collider and Platform Effector. Let me remind you that the game is in 2D. I have the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DefaultPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        // Get the Rigidbody2D component from the collided object
        Rigidbody2D rb = collision.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        // Update only the vertical velocity, preserving the horizontal velocity
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 8f);
    }
}
```

It allows you to jump up when you hit a collider of platform, but if such platforms are very close to each other along the Y-axis, then the player does not choose the highest platform to jump from, but jumps from all collider of platforms that come on the way. Please help me! I have no idea how to solve this.

I tried to use **coroutines** to wait a few seconds after the jump. I tried to use the **canJump** and **isPlayerOnPlatform** variables, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you please show some code sample + screenshot of the game/situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need complex system with Edge Collider and Platform Effector, just simple BoxCollider2D.
Make BoxCollider2D on all platforms triggers (IsTrigger check).
In `OnTriggerEnter2D` method ([wiki](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html)) of the class, attached to the platform gameObject check player's velocity on Y-axis (your player must have Rigidbody). If it's pointing upwards, then do nothing, but if it's going down, then initialize player jump.